# Recursive type synonyms in Haskell - 'cycle in type synonym declarations'

Tags: haskell, types

I'm currently reading the [CSP Book](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf) by CAR Hoare, and trying to implement its early examples using Haskell.

The book starts by defining a process algebra - essentially, processes take events and either return another process or a symbol (`bleep`) indicating that the process does not engage in this event. The `STOP` process is one which returns `bleep` for any event.

The book suggests that you do this in a LISP, so I used Racket. The definition of `STOP` is very simple:

```
(define (STOP event) 'bleep)
```

as is a 'vending machine' process which takes only the event `coin` and returns `STOP`:

```
(define (coin-to-stop event)
  (case event
    ['coin STOP]
    [else 'bleep]))
```

I then tried to implement these same concepts in Haskell. We don't have symbols like Racket does, so let's define `Event`:

```
data Event = Ev String deriving (Eq)
```

Unlike Racket, we can't just fudge the difference between a `'bleep` and a process, so we'll use `Maybe` to define the type of a process:

```
type Process = Event -> Maybe Process
```

Where `Just p` corresponds to a process, and `Nothing` corresponds to `'bleep`.

Now we can define the `STOP` process:

```
stop :: Process
stop _ = Nothing
```

and the 'vending machine' process:

```
coinToStop :: Process
coinToStop (Ev "coin") = Just stop
coinToStop _           = Nothing
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, because you can't have cyclical type definitions:

```
Cycle in type synonym declarations:
  src\Csp.hs: type Process = Event -> Maybe Process
```

I played around with `newtype` for a bit, but I don't really understand what I'm doing there.

I realise that I could implement a roughly equivalent solution using:

```
data ProcResult = P (Maybe Process)
type Process = Event -> ProcResult
```

but this seems unnecessarily ugly.

What would be the correct way to represent the concept of a `Process` in Haskell?

Comment: `newtype Process = Process (Event -> Maybe Process)` should work.

Comment: You might want to look at the [`chp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/chp-2.2.0.1) package - seems they define a process as a monad.

Comment: your signatures seem wrong (`stop`, `coinToStop` take parameter you define them as constants)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has three sorts of type definitions:

1. `data`: Defines a "full-blown" data type.
2. `newtype`: Defines an "isomorphic" type, which is something like an *opaque type synonym*.
3. `type`: Defines a transparent type synonym.  Like a `typedef` in C/C++.

So you're using `type` and trying to define a recursive type synonym:

```
type Process = Event -> Maybe Process
```

Well, one rule in Haskell is that in any case where you have a `type` synonym, you can substitute it with its expansion and the program works the same.  And Haskell will expand `type` synonyms in order to figure out what type they stand for.  So when you write this:

```
stop :: Process
```

You're asking Haskell to expand it this way:

```
stop :: Event -> Maybe Process
stop :: Event -> Maybe (Event -> Maybe Process)
stop :: Event -> Maybe (Event -> Maybe (Event -> Maybe Process))
     .
     .
     .
```

To make the long story short, `type` synonyms in Haskell aren't allowed to be recursive at all.  `newtype` and `data` are allowed to be recursive, so that's why you should use `newtype` here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to n.m., I figured out a solution:

```
data Event = Ev String deriving (Eq)
newtype Process = Process { run :: Event -> Maybe Process }
                  deriving (Show)

stop :: Process
stop = Process (const Nothing)

coin :: Event
coin = Ev "coin"

coinAccepter :: Process
coinAccepter = Process (\x -> case x of 
                                (Ev "coin") -> Just stop
                                _           -> Nothing)

prefix :: Event -> Process -> Process
prefix c p = Process (\x -> if x == c then Just p else Nothing)
```

Now time to go and learn how I can chain `run`s together with `bind`...